# Dynamic Arrays, Destructor, Deep Copying help needed

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, deep-copy

Okay, so the here is things that I still need to do. I am having some serious problems with syntax. I don't know why I am getting an error when I try to declare a dynamically allocated array. It would be great if I could get some help on this.

`BabyNames` class:

1. Should have as data members:

   - a dynamically allocated array of Data objects
   - an int data member that represents the capacity of the array
   - an int data member to keep track of how many array locations have Data objects in them.
2. Besides one or more "regular" constructors, also implement
   i. a copy constructor that performs a “deep” copy – use this to make the copies.
   ii. an overloaded assignment operator
   iii. a virtual destructor to deallocate any memory allocated by any of the constructors.
3. Overload the insertion (`<<`) and extraction (`>>`) operators.

Here is the header

```
        /*
 * File:   BabyNames.h
 * Author: jack
 *
 * Created on March 18, 2013, 3:35 PM
 */

#ifndef BABYNAMES_H_
#define BABYNAMES_H_
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using std::ifstream;

/**
 * gender: an enum to hold types boy and girl
 */
enum gender {boy, girl};

/**
 * PeopleStats: a data struct to hold year, name, double, and the enum type
 * gender
 */
struct PeopleStats {
    short year;
    string name;
    double percent;
    gender sex;
};

/**
 * Names: A class that reads data from a file into a PeopleStats Array
 * and is capable of sorting them by name and by popularity percentage
 */
class BabyNames {

public:
    BabyNames();
    BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines);
    gender parseSex(string s);
    void swap(int i);
    const int getCapacity();//getter for dataSize
    const PeopleStats& get(int i) const; //getter for objects of the data array
    void sortByName();      //Sorts the names alphabetically
    void sortByPopularity();//Sorts the names by popularity
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BabyNames& bn);
    //friend std::PeopleStats& operator =(const PeopleStats& rhs);

private:
    static const int MAX_DATA_SIZE = 25000;
    PeopleStats* people; 

    int capacity;
    int fillCount; // to keep track of how many array locations have data objects in them
    static const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS = -1;

};//end of class

#endif  /* BABYNAMES_H */
```

Here is the functions

```
/**
 * PeopleSort.cpp
 * Description:
 * This class stores the information in data structure and includes methods that
 * sort the data by name and by popularity.
 * Created:
 * Feb 27, 2013
 * Modified:
 * March 1st 2013
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using std::ifstream;
#include "BabyNames.h"

/**
 * BabyNames: A class that reads data from a file into a PeopleStats Array
 * and is capable of sorting them by name and by popularity percentage
 */

BabyNames::BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines) {
    people = new PeoplStats[MAX_DATA_SIZE]; //edit I put this in but I still get errors
    //set current capacity
    capacity = numLines;
    //Open File
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fn);
    //read in data
    int current = 0;
    while (current < capacity) {
        myfile >> people[current].year;
        myfile >> people[current].name;
        myfile >> people[current].percent;
        string sex;
        myfile >> sex;
        people[current].sex = parseSex(sex);
        current++;
    }

}

BabyNames::~BabyNames(){
    cout << "Deconstructor" << endl;
    delete[]people; //Edit: I added this
}

/*
 * sortByName - Sorts the entire array of people by name using the bubble
 * sort algorithm. Array is sorted according to name, within the structure
 * Algorithm becomes extremely slow if capacity > 3000
 */
void BabyNames::sortByName(){
    //sorted is set to true if no changes were made
    bool sorted = false;
    //change tells the loop if we made a swap or not
    bool change = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
            int compare = people[i].name.compare(people[i + 1].name);
            if (compare == 1) {
                swap(i);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        //if the array was not changed,
        //changed sorted to true and exit loop
        if (change == false)
            sorted = true;
        //otherwise reset change and repeat the loop
        else
            change = false;
    }
}

/**
 * sortByPopularity - sorts the entire array using the bubble sort algorithm
 * Method is almost exactly the same as sortByName, except the compare
 * variable is a double consisting of the difference of the two popularity
 * percentages.
 * Algorithm becomes extremely slow if capacity > 3000
 */
void BabyNames::sortByPopularity(){
    bool sorted = false;
    bool change = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
            double compare = people[i].percent - people[i + 1].percent;
            if (compare < 0) {
                swap(i);
                change = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (change == false)
            sorted = true;
        change = false;
    }
}

/**
 * swap - swaps the positions of people[i] and people[i + 1]
 * @param i - index of the people array that will get swapped with i + 1
 */
void BabyNames::swap(int i) {
    PeopleStats temp = people[i + 1];
    people[i + 1] = people[i];
    people[i] = temp;
}
/**
 * parseSex: extracts the gender from the input and returns the appropriate enum
 * @param s
 * @return gender object
 */
gender BabyNames::parseSex(string s) {
    if (s == "boy")
        return boy;
    else if (s == "girl")
        return girl;
    else
        throw "invalid Gender";
}

/**
 * getCapacity: returns the number of data entries stored.
 * @return size of the data
 */
const int BabyNames::getCapacity(){
    return capacity;
}
/**
 * get: returns one PeopleStat Object
 * @param i
 * @require: i < capacity
 * @return PeopleStat object
 */
const PeopleStats& BabyNames::get(int i) const {
    if (i>=0 && i < capacity)
        return people[i];
    throw OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
}
/**
 * << - overloads the outstream operator for PeopleStats object
 * @param os
 * @param d
 * @return os : output stream
 */
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream& os, const PeopleStats& d){
    os << d.name << " " << d.year << " " << d.percent << " " << d.sex;
    return os;
}

/**
 * <<: overloads the outstream operator for the BabyNames object
 * @param os
 * @param bn
 * @return
 */
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BabyNames& bn) {
    os << "  BabyNames object " << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 5000; i++ )
        os << "    " << (i+1) <<":  " << bn.get( i ) << std::endl;
    return os;
}//end of operator
```

Here is the main

```
/*Title: CS 237 Assignment#1

 * Created:
 * Feb 27, 2013
 * Modified:
 * March 1st 2013
 ********************************/

#include <iostream>
#include "BabyNames.h"

/**
 * main: The client function that controls the server, BabyNames
 * For reasons currently unknown, the program will take forever
 * to run after the  * 3000-5000 line mark.
 * @return 0 if successful
 */
int main(void) {
    cout << "People names: " << endl;
    BabyNames names("src/people.txt", 5000 );
    cout << names;
    cout << "Sorted by popularity" << endl;
    names.sortByPopularity();
    cout << names;
//    cout << "Sorted by name" << endl;
//    names.sortByName();
//    cout << names;
    cout << "... done!" << endl;
    return 0;


//This is a suggested Main by my professor
/*    cout << "People names: " << endl;
    const char filename[] = "src/people.txt";
    cout << " 1. Reading file: \"" << filename << "\" ... ";
    int number_of_names = checklines( filename );
    cout << " number of lines in file is: " << number_of_names;
    BabyNames* names = new BabyNames( number_of_names );

    // read the contents of a file into names and print them
    ifstream file( filename, ios::in );
    file >> *names;
    cout << " file has been read!" << endl;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 2. Sorted by popularity:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByPop = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByPop->sortByPopularity();
    cout << *namesByPop;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 3. Sorted by name:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByName = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByName->sortByName();
    cout << *namesByName;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 4. Sorted by year:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByYear = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByYear->sortByYear();
    cout << *namesByYear;

    cout << " 5. Original names:" << endl;
    cout << *names;

    delete names;
    delete namesByYear;
    delete namesByName;
    delete namesByPop;*/



    cout << "... all done!" << endl;

}
```

Also, the file that I am reading has a lot of lines that look like this

```
1880 John 0.081541 boy
1880 William 0.080511 boy
1880 James 0.050057 boy
1880 Charles 0.045167 boy
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How would I add some of the things I listed at the top?

Comment: Just some tips: 1)You haven't defined your destructor in your header file. 2) don't put `using namespace` in your header file, put it in your `.cpp` file. 3) If you are already stating `using namespace std;` then `using std::ifstream;` is pointless. 4) Why not use a `list` or `vector`?

Comment: Thanks Nima! 1) Cool, it worked, now I don't get an error with it. 2) I get an error if I have the namespace in just the .cpp. 3) it is good to know that std::ifsteam is pointless if namespace std is being used.I deleted the ifstream. 4) It is a school assignment and the professor doesn't want a list or a vector used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I see where you actually allocate the memory in your constructor.

```
BabyNames::BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines) {
    people = new PeopleStats[numLines];
    // check for null
    .....
}
```

Also, free the memory in your destructor:

```
BabyNames::~BabyNames() {
    delete [] people;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps, although I still get errors when I i have people = new PeopleStats[numLines]; in the constructor. Multiple markers at this line - Type 'PeoplStats' could not be resolved - expected type-specifier before ‘PeoplStats’ - expected ‘;’ before ‘PeoplStats’ - cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘PeopleStats*’ in assignment

Comment: You have a typo: 'PeoplStats' (missing 'e').

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are having problems with the following line in the header:

```
PeopleStats* people = new PeopleStats[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
```

You can't dynamically allocate memory in the header.  Which is why it won't compile.  You will have to dynamically allocate the memory in a cpp file.  You just need to declare a pointer in the header (as you have already done).  Then, in the constructor for the class, allocate the memory before you try to access it.

Header:

```
class BabyNames {
public:
    BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines);
    ~BabyNames();

private:
    PeopleStats* people;
};
```

cpp file:

```
BabyNames::BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines) {
    // dynamicall allocate array
    people = new PeopleStats[numLines];

    // fill in people array here
}

~BabyNames::BabyNames {
    // don't forget to free array or you will have a memory leak
    delete [] people;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps, although I still get errors when I i have people = new PeopleStats[numLines]; in the constructor.

Multiple markers at this line
- Type 'PeoplStats' could not be resolved
- expected type-specifier before ‘PeoplStats’
- expected ‘;’ before ‘PeoplStats’
- cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘PeopleStats*’ in assignment